# Кастомные поля для каждого типа товаров

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, интернет-магазин

Здравствуйте. Пишу магазин.

При проектировке БД возник след. вопрос: 
Как спроектировать базу так, чтобы для каждого вида товаров были свои уникальные поля. Т.е., если скажем тип товара телевизор, то для него имеют место следующие поля: диагональ, разрешение, тип экрана и прочие атрибуты свойственные только для телика и ничего лишнего. Если товар кофемашина, то будут такие поля как, тип машины, тип кофе, объем, давление и т.д.

Предполагается также, что для всех видов товаров будут некие общие поля как скажем: название товара, цена, производитель и т.д.

Поля будут создаваться из админки. Т.е. зашел в админку, создал тип товара "телевизоры" и тут же к нему добавил поля.

Как лучше спроектировать структуру БД для решения этой задачи? Обычно использую MySql InnoDb. Подойдет ли он для этой задачи?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Отдельная таблица для параметров товаров. Пример:

**product** таблица товаров

- id
- deleted

**products_options** таблица параметров товаров

- id
- product_id
- name
- value

В этом случае для любого товара можно создать любые параметры.

Comment: Ага, холодильник "Минск-110" свой набор параметров, холодильник "Минск-110а" при вводе ошиблись в имени 1го параметра и привет, товары не сравнить

Comment: Во первых. Для товаров необходимо завести тип, каждый тип будет иметь свой набор параметров по умолчанию. Во вторых. Система сравнения должна учитывать типы товаров для сравнения.

Answer (score 3):

Ну по классике идет таблица товаров с общими для всех товаров полями
Такими как Id, название, возможно тут же описание, если оно точно одно. Ссылку на главное изображение. Вот цену я бы так сразу сюда пихать не стал. Как минимум могут потребоваться для анализа старые цены или ввести цены начиная с завтрашнего дня, а текущие применять сегодня. В общем цены это отдельный разговор, надо детально изучать как их принято назначать и от чего они могут зависеть (не забываем скидки).

Вторая таблица типы товаров. И вот тут похоже нам нужно наследование:

```
ID типа товара
Наименование типа
Является подтипом для типа ID
Возможно какие то доп. признаки: показывать ли покупателям и еще какие-то
    (например, мы делаем для покупателей просто тип "Холодильники", а нам самим для себя
     их надо различать по какому то неинтересному покупателю критерию,
     но при этом для данного критерия немного другой набор возможных параметров)
```

Наследование конечно усложняет, но по моему оно необходимо. У всех велосипедов один набор параметров, но у шоссейных могут быть свои доп. параметры. Кроме того обычно интерфейс для покупателя так и выглядит "Велосипеды-> Детские, Шоссейные, ...". Конкретному товару в базе при этом назначается только ID самого подробного типа к которому он относится. Остальное наследование раскручивается древовидно по этой таблице.

Третья таблица возможные параметры типа товаров

```
- ID параметра
- ID типа товара
- Наименование параметра
- Тип параметра (что бы хоть числа от строк отличать и сортировку правильную делать)
- Возможно флаг: Постоянный/переменный параметр
- Возможно признак "Важного параметра", выводимого в заголовок товара например
- И может быть потребуются группы типов параметров. У телефонов будет 'цвет',
но и у холодильников есть 'цвет'. Вряд-ли будет смысл сравнивать телефоны с холодильниками
но всякое бывает и может потребоваться. Сразу городить не стоит, но при дальнейшей
постановке или  реализации может всплыть.
```

Постоянные параметры - это те, что у товара всегда, данная модель холодильника всегда с 2мя камерами. А вот цвет - переменный параметр, он может отличатся у конкретных экземпляров. Но что самое неприятное, складские остатки по белым и зеленым холодильникам разные. Да, часто их просто как 2 отдельных товара заводят и тут уже серьезный вопрос будет какая то связь между ними или нет. Лично мне было бы удобно зайти на страницу с нужной мне моделью и там уже выбрать цвет. А не листать в общем списке товаров серо-буро-малиновые модификации. Хотя временами от цвета цена зависит ...

А вот теперь самое интересное, хранение параметров конкретного товара. НФ5 говорит нам, что мы должны сделать простейшую таблицу

```
ID товара
ID параметра
значение (думаю просто текстовое поле)
```

Если нам надо реально в SQL запросах искать по этим параметрам - то такая структура необходима. Но вот при выборке конкретного товара из базы для отображения вытягивание этих записей может быть медленным. И тогда я бы предложил при записи в эту таблицу делать сразу (например триггерами) собранное значение всех параметров товара в JSON или в другом формате и класть отдельно. Возможно проще прочитать из базы одну запись товара и сразу иметь на руках все его параметры. Но это если не предусмотрено кеширование более крупных объектов, например собранного html кода для отображения данного товара.

Answer (score 1):

Небольшая модификация версии Mike

Третья таблица возможные параметры типа товаров

```
- ID параметра
- Наименование параметра
- Тип параметра (что бы хоть числа от строк отличать и сортировку правильную  делать)
- И может быть потребуются группы типов параметров. У телефонов будет 'цвет',
но и у холодильников есть 'цвет'. Вряд-ли будет смысл сравнивать телефоны с  холодильниками
но всякое бывает и может потребоваться. Сразу городить не стоит, но при дальнейшей
постановке или  реализации может всплыть.
```

Четвёртая таблица параметров для типа товара

```
- ID типа товара
- ID параметра
- Возможно флаг: Постоянный/переменный параметр
- Возможно признак "Важного параметра", выводимого в заголовок товара например
```

Таблицы типов товаров и возможных параметров связаны отношением многие-ко-многим. Цвет он и в Африке цвет. Можно обойтись одним параметром "цвет" вместо двух "цвет холодильника" и "цвет телефона".

То, что вы ищите, называется Entity–attribute–value model. Может быть очень неприятным занятием в реляционных базах.

Comment: Соглашусь, один параметр для разных типов товаров, выражающий свою физическую сущность это правильно. Вдруг акцию магазин захочет провести к первому мая "На все красное скидка 10%" :)  Правда с точки зрения пользователя слишком мудрено выходит