# Организация структуры хранения данных в MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, оптимизация

Существует список товаров, у которых есть ряд характеристик. У товаров есть общие  характеристики: например, вес и размер. Есть и уникальные характеристики у некоторых товаров, например, цвет (в дополнение к первым двум). Различных уникальных характеристик у разных товаров может быть до сотни и задача — организовать хранение  таким образом, чтобы значение той или иной характеристики могло работать в WHERE.

Планирую занести каждую из возможных характеристик в отдельный столбец, в связи с чем вопрос: насколько сильно снижается производительность БД в зависимости от количества столбцов, если столбцов будет до сотни? Может быть есть более оптимальный способ хранения и обработки данных в этой ситуации?

Comment: Более оптимального точно нет. Есть менее оптимальный, но более универсальный. У вас же характеристики будут сейчас жестко зашиты в коде и добавление новой характеристики - модификация кода

Comment: Вот что то подобное обсуждалось, правда там еще типы товаров присутствовали, каждый со своим перечнем характеристик http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/466357/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2/466379#466379

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и за ссылку, Mike. Я опасался, что с сотней столбцов с производительностью будут проблемы. Если это более оптимальное решение в плане производительности, то на нем и остановлюсь. Вшить в структуру таблицы все характеристики, по которым может применяться условие WHERE, мне проблемой не кажется.

Comment: Я совершенно забыл, что вам для поиска понадобится строить индекс ... В общем все соображения в ответе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хранить массу параметров можно двумя способами, как вы предложили - параметр -  колонка. И в виде отдельной таблицы, где для каждой записи из основной таблицы лежат много записей, в которых id основной записи, id типа параметра и значение этого параметра.

У обоих подходов есть свои плюсы и минусы. Когда параметры отдельно и отдельными строками, зато колонка со значением параметра только одна, по этой колонке можно построить индекс и моментально находить id нужных записей по значению параметра. С другой стороны, когда надо просто показать все параметры к конкретному товару начинает тормозить выборка каждого параметра отдельной строкой. Если параметров сотня - это довольно накладно.

При вашем подходе выборка из таблицы товаров по id товара будет моментальной, все параметры лежат в одной записи, значит за одну дисковую операцию мы получаем все, что нам надо знать про товар. Это отлично. НО
на 100 колонок строить индексы нельзя, ибо каждый дополнительный индекс занимает много места на диске и замедляет вставку новых записей, потому как при вставке записи каждый индекс должен быть частично перестроен. А раз мы оставляем колонки с значениями параметров без индексов, то любой поиск по ним будет вынужден читать с диска всю таблицу. Кроме того при таком подходе при добавлении нового параметра надо добавлять новую колонку, явно указывать ее в выборках и возможно упоминать о ней в разных частях кода.

Есть третий подход. Хранить значения атрибутов и в виде колонок и в виде записей в отдельной таблице. Для поиска по значения параметров используется отдельная таблица. А при показе конкретного товара данные берутся прямо из основной записи. Да, этот подход вносит избыточность данных. При изменении любого параметра его надо изменить в двух местах. В принципе это можно делать триггерами для надежности. Изменения будут немного дольше, чем при работе только с одной таблицей.

В общем *истина где то рядом*, надо искать баланс. Возможно часть атрибутов держать в двух местах, а какие нибудь второстепенные параметры держать только в поисковой таблице, но не держать в основной.