# Сущность с переменным количеством атрибутов

Tags: база-данных, проектирование

Какой способ наиболее приемлем для хранения характеристик товаров? К примеру, чтобы охарактеризовать резистор (пример из моей предметной области) достаточно атрибутов мощность и сопротивление, конденсатор - емкость и напряжение, транзистор - целая куча атрибутов.

Моя идея:

Сущность "предмет" хранит id, название и остаток товаров, сущность "характеристика" относится к ней один-к-одному и содержит всевозможные атрибуты характеристики и их значения.

Недостатки:

Чрезмерное количество NULL значений, количество атрибутов зависит от типа, который ещё каким-то образом нужно проверять, отбрасывая лишние атрибуты.

Comment: Подобные вопросы минимум раз в месяц тут пробегают. поищите. обычно все таки делают вертикальную таблицу. Объект-ID_атрибута-Значение. И справочник возможных атрибутов. Но доставать атрибуты не очень удобно, зато поиск можно унифицировать

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483000/%D0%9E%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-mysql/483150#483150

Comment: А что у вас за БД? В mongo переменное количество атрибутов - естественное явление, и никаких тебе null значений, может вам нужна документ-ориентированная БД вместо того чтоб костыли вместо колес приделывать к инвалидной коляске?

Comment: @Mike то есть таблица "параметры", "товары" и связующая их третья таблица? В таком случае добавление нового конденсатора автоматически добавляет две записи в третью таблицу, как я понимаю. Но где будет хранится информация о том, какой товар сколько атрибутов характеристики имеет?

Comment: @Darth реляционная. Буду рад услышать проверенные способы прикрутить Mogno к Flask, типа SQLAlchemy для реляционок.

Comment: У вас ведь какие нибудь "виды товаров" или "категории" есть ? ну вот те самые "конденсатор", "транзистор". Вот к ним и сделать табличку которая будет содержать допустимые для них атрибуты

Comment: @jumpjet67 в реляционной бд можно сделать поле атрибуты и класть туда внутрь json - строку. вот почитайте https://habrahabr.ru/post/254425/

Comment: Уже пятый за месяц с характеристикам товаров. [Entity–attribute–value model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)