# Как реализовать многочисленные характеристики?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Как правильно построить таблицу для характеристик?
Вот например в инет магазинах характеристики делуются так:
Дисплей
Диагональ.........5 дюймов
Разрешение........1920х1080
Получается 3 таблици группа | характеристика | значение, а еще надо это все к товару привязать,и по ним фильтровать потом.
Помогите правильно составить базу для них.

Comment: Например http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483000/ и это пятисекундный поиск. А так таких вопросов тут масса

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно что то не подумал в поиск вбить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте подходы к проектированию базы данных:

1. **Class Table Inheritance** - наследование таблиц
2. **Entity-Attributes-Values (EAV)** - запись всех параметров в одну таблицу

Первый подход более правильный с точки зрения проектирования РСУБД и сложный при большом кол-ве параметров, второй более гибкий, простой, следовательно менее производительный. У каждого способа есть свои плюсы и минусы.

Точного варианта, что лучше использовать нет, каждый ищет для себя **золотую середину**.